# Bad css in html

Tags: html, css

So i tried to make Form web for school project and i Did the html part and then went to css and it tells me there is some sort of error. I tried css Validator and it said Expected LBRACE.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ooioooooopopopop.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <div class="1">
        <label for="name">Your Name</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="name"
          name="visitor_name"
          placeholder="John Doe"
          required
        />
      </div>

      <div class="1">
        <label for="email">Your E-mail</label>
        <input
          type="email"
          id="email"
          name="visitor_email"
          placeholder="john.doe@email.com"
          required
        />
      </div>
      <div class="1">
        <label for="phone">Your Phone</label>
        <input
          type="tel"
          id="phone"
          name="visitor_phone"
          placeholder="777 555 782"
          required
        />
      </div>

      <div class="2">
        <label for="adult">Adults</label>

        <input type="number" id="adult" name="total_adults" placeholder="2" min="1" required>
      </div>

      <div class="2">
        <label for="child">Children</label>
        <input type="number" id="child" name="total_children" placeholder="2" min="0" required>
      </div>

      <div class="2">
        <label for="checkin-date">Check-in Date</label>
        <input type="date" id="checkin-date" name="checkin" required>
      </div>

      <div class="2">
        <label for="checkout-date">Check-out Date</label>
        <input type="date" id="checkout-date" name="checkout" required>
      </div>

      <div class="1">
        <label for="room-selection">Select Room Preference</label>
        <select id="room-selection" name="room_preference" required>
            <option value="">Choose a Room from the List</option>
            <option value="big">Big</option>
            <option value="medium">Medium</option>
            <option value="small"></option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="elem-group">
        <label for="message">Anything Else?</label>
        <textarea id="message" name="visitor_message" placeholder="Tell us anything else that might be important." required></textarea>
      </div>
      
      <button type="submit">Book The Rooms</button>
    </form>
</main>

  </body>
</html>
```

and my css:

```
body {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 50px;
}

div.1 {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

div.2 {
  width: 39%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 1%;
}

label {
  display: block;
  font-family: "Nanum Gothic";
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
}

input,
select,
textarea {
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 2px solid #777;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-family: "Nanum Gothic";
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
}

div.1 input {
  width: 95%;
  display: inline-block;
}

textarea {
  height: 250px;
}

hr {
  border: 1px dotted #ccc;
}

button {
  height: 50px;
  background: orange;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-family: "Nanum Gothic";
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button:hover {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

Basicaly i tried to take inspo from some website i found some time ago (dont remember what it was i just had the code saved) And changed it a bit. Any help on how to make this css/ html correct would be appreciated.

Comment: Edit your question and format it correctly. Also, this is not a place to solve your homework.

Comment: Basically, I suspect this is caused by your class names being numbers.

Comment: `div.1` - `.1` is not a valid class selector. You would have to _escape_ this (details: https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes) - but it really makes much more sense, if you simply try to avoid class names that start with a digit.